# dijit/form/numberspinner not working

Tags: validation, dojo, dijit.form

http://jsfiddle.net/sMRP9/

In the above link you can check.. using version dojo 1.8 but I am unable to make a number spinner. Still a textbox is appearing instead of a textbox with spinner.

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner"
    id="strokewidth"
   value=100
    data-dojo-props="smallDelta:10,
constraints:{min:9,max:155,places:0},
largeDelta:10 "

    />​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a couple of issues with the jsfiddle I [updated it](http://jsfiddle.net/sMRP9/1/) with the following

1. Wrap widgets with `<body class="claro">` tag
2. Add claro.css resource
3. Require in dojo/parser and call parse

Markup:

```
<body class="claro">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner"
    id="strokewidth"
   value="1000"
    data-dojo-props="smallDelta:10,
constraints:{min:9,max:155,places:0},
largeDelta:10 "

    />
</body>​
```

js:

```
require(['dijit/form/NumberSpinner','dojo/parser'],function(NumberSpinner,parser){
    parser.parse();
});​
```

Comment: if i want to add event in this spinner... that is byusing the id of the spiner if i want to invoke a function. how is that possible ?